# Chrome stops iframe loading, if an alert persist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

Firefox continues to load the iframe in the background.
But Chrome stops loading anything until the alert Ok button is clicked

Here is the example code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hai") },10);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/jQuery/" style="margin-top:100px" height="100" width="100"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have the click event on `p` but it is not in the code ?

Comment: I believe the click event has nothing to do with the question